When is a real analytic subvariety complex?
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $Y\subset X$ a real analytic subvariety, not necessarily smooth. Suppose that there is a dense open subset $U\subset Y$ such that $U$ is a complex analytic subvariety of $X$. Does it follow that $Y$ is a complex analytic subvariety?
